# how to insert another row in between two rows on sqlite manager

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am typing the words alphabetically on sqlite in tabular form and it's been numbered...assuming i wanna add a row in  between two rows on sylite manager maybe number 2 is "aa" and number 3 is "ac" if i wanna add "ab"  in between aa and ac and make ab number 3 and ac number 4, how am i gonna do it easily?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[`DBFiddle Demo of Update Statement`](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=226b3246712152fec98bb569bb2ccf5a)**</kbd>

As sqlite don't support windows analytical function, it would be bit tricky to achieve this. You can also use similar logic to create a `before insert` trigger.

Assumptions:

1. Number starts with any integer, like `2` in this case and will increment by `1`. So there are no missing sequence in your existing data.
2. Alphanumeric sorting is applicable where `aa` < `aaa` < `ab` < `ac`. This is done by the RDBMS based on ascii values of the each character of string, starting from first one.
3. You are inserting a value `ab` without any `id`. After the run of below update statement, `id` will be assigned to this `val`. You can achieve the same with `before insert` trigger, by using similar logic.

First Query to determine the `new_id`.

```
select t.*,
    (select count(*) from test t1 where t.val>=t1.val)  +
        o.diff as new_id
from test t
cross join 
(select * from 
    (select t.*,(select count(*) from test t1 where t.val>=t1.val) as rn ,
        id - (select count(*) from test t1 where t.val>=t1.val)  as diff 
    from test t
    ) where rn=1
) o
```

Output

```
+------+-----+--------+
|  id  | val | new_id |
+------+-----+--------+
| 2    | aa  |      2 |
| 3    | ac  |      4 |
| null | ab  |      3 |
+------+-----+--------+
```

I am using `cross join` as first we have to determine the `difference` of `min_id` with actual `id`. Like in above case, if we generate number from `1` to `n`, your id starts with `2`. So the `diff` of these two is `1`, which I would use to add in all of generated ids, to get `new_id`. May be there is an easier approach for it, but this is all I can think of right now.

Now we use this query in the update statement to update `id` with `new_id`.

```
update test
set id = (select tb.new_id from 
            (select t.*,
                (select count(*) from test t1 where t.val>=t1.val)  +
                    o.diff as new_id
                from test t
            cross join 
                (select * from 
                    (select t.*,(select count(*) from test t1 where t.val>=t1.val) as rn ,
                        id - (select count(*) from test t1 where t.val>=t1.val)  as diff 
                    from test t
                    ) where rn=1
                ) o
            ) tb
            where test.val=tb.val 
        )
where exists
    ( select * From (select t.*,
                        (select count(*) from test t1 where t.val>=t1.val)  +
                            o.diff as new_id
                        from test t
                    cross join 
                        (select * from 
                            (select t.*,(select count(*) from test t1 where t.val>=t1.val) as rn ,
                                id - (select count(*) from test t1 where t.val>=t1.val)  as diff 
                            from test t
                            ) where rn=1
                        ) o
                    ) tb 
    where test.val=tb.val
    );
```